# Instagram API calls limit

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

Dear Instagram developers team,

Our team is currently in the design phase of a connector to Instagram API for our application. 
We bumped into a few questions related to the Instagram API [limits](https://www.instagram.com/developer/limits/).

- Would you consider the following scenario as a bad practice?

  1. use all 60 per hour calls for an endpoint until connector receives a 429 response code form the Instagram API
  2. when the first 429 response is received the connector stops calling the Instagram API for 5 minutes, then try again
  3. If the response was successful, continue from step #1, if not - increase 'sleeping time' by 5 minutes each attempt until the call is
     successful and then continue from step #1
- How many calls that return 429 code our connector can make in an hour
  so its behavior would not be considered spammy? Can we make lets say
  20 such calls in a row? The question raised because of the very last
  sentence on the [limits](https://www.instagram.com/developer/limits/) page.

  > You may also receive responses with an HTTP response code of 400 (Bad Request) if we detect spammy behavior by a person using your
  >   app. These errors are unrelated to rate limiting.
- Per hour limit means that at the beginning of an hour the entire limit is
  reset or it means that once an API call is made, the available limit will be increased by one after one hour? The second scenario means that if I made 30 calls in one minute and then another 30 after half an hour, when one hour plus one minute passes from the first call only 30 calls will be available.
- Is there a way to increase limits for POST or DELETE calls?

Thank you

Comment: What is it your building that requires so many API calls? Instragram have put limits in to avoid such behaviour, so the question may be, “How can I do what I need to do more efficiently?” rather than, “How can I make more API calls than I’m allowed to?”

Comment: Hey @MartinBean. Thanks for your comment. Thing is: the application might have a few hundreds thousand or even millions Instagram followers. I would be happy if you can suggest something that allows to fit all required calls in 60 per hour during a campaign. Open to any suggestions.